# Version 1.6.0 token input is not allowing custom entry

Tags: jquery-tokeninput

In rails project, i am trying to implement jquery token input (version 1.6.0) plugin.
According to the below code, token input is not allowing custom entry. It will select the value which is only in list.

Eg:

```
   jQuery("#text_box_id").tokenInput(go_to_url, {
      tokenLimit: 20,
      allowCustomEntry: true,
      preventDuplicates: true
    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Token Input - allowCustomEntry not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974977/jquery-token-input-allowcustomentry-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

What custom entry do you require? If you want the value the user has entered, you could manually add this value to the json object that you return to jquery-tokeninput success callback.